# little doable or very little to do?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, grammaticality, punctuation, semicolons

which is the most grammatical of those sentences?

1. There is very little doable about this issue, we just have to work harder.
2. Other than working harder, we can do little about this issue.
3. There is very little to do about this issue; we just have to work harder.

> Although they all might be correct, I would like to know which one is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are my suggestions: There is little else we can do about this issue except work harder or other than work harder there is little else we can do about this issue.

Comment: Thank you , but I do not have except three choices. Your suggestion is not one of them

Comment: I would opt for number 2.

Comment: The second choice is the correct one :)